# Having all object fields at once with out typing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have some classes with more than 30 attributes in Entity Frame Work model designer (Data base first approach) mapping to their corresponding tables. It's clear that I need to make an instance of those classes and then assigning all their fields values, that is kind of boring, repetitive and also bug prone because you may miss some assignments. I think It would be nice If I could just type the instance name of a class and then the IDE or something like code snippet pops up all it's fields at once. Do you know any work around other than just Copying them from Model.designer.cs (in c#)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using `AutoMapper`?  You can get it using `NuGet`

Here's an article that outlines it's usage: http://csharppulse.blogspot.in/2013/08/crud-operations-using-automapper-in-c_381.html

Comment: thanks. it's so useful. but what if I want to assign values from controls in win or wpf applications?

Answer (score 0):

1]I think you can use the `Add Code Generation Item`, but I havent actually used this myself.  I believe you can use this go generate a `.tt` file, which will then generate simple `POCO's` based on your EF objects.

Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456821.aspx) for examples.

Comment: thanks but they are not what I need. I need to type the instance name, hitting tab keyword twice (for example) and then all object fields be appears. just like what we have using code snippet.

Comment: What about them is not what you need, to me using POCO's looks like exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I think he might be looking for a way to do, `var newEntity = new Entity {//properties automatically appear here}`.  Similar to SQL Prompt, when you do `Insert Into table`...then SQL prompt auto generates the columns...at least this is what I think :)

Comment: Ahh, I see. I guess just making a constructor in a separate partial class from the auto-generated code that takes in all the properties would be the solution (too tired to write it up as a full answer)